# How to clear ssh keys from windows that are used by git to login?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I learned from other questions here (please correct me if I am wrong), that github identifies users based on the ssh keys that it sees on my computer (in the .ssh folder). Now, here's an odd one:

I have 2 regular, free, github accounts. Let's say they're Auser and Buser.
At the moment I'm not really using Buser, and I need to only use Auser. In the past, I have used Buser as well.

Currently in my .ssh folder I have only 2 files id_rsa and its corresponding id_rsa.pub. I know I'm not supposed to keep by pub like around like this, but that's beside the point at the moment.

So, I went to Auser's setting page on github and uploaded the pub. Next thing I do is check that everything is set properly so I:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi userA! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So far, so good, so I start working, stage, commit, push, no errors. Then I check my work on github:

> Buser commited 2 minutes ago

I figure that probably Buser has the same ssh key set up, even though I read that github doesn't allow, and prevents this to happe. I login to github in browser with Buser to check what key is set up. I was already kind of excited that I was found a bug in github which allowed me to use the same key on 2 accounts. Not little was my surprise when I saw that no key is actually saved Buser's settings under SSH keys.

More, possibly relevant details:

- Buser, or the email associated with Buser is nowhere in git config settings, not at global level, not at repository level.
- No github related credentials are saved in Windows, unless they are saved with a completely different name that doesn't resemble github.
- Buser does not have push permissions to the newly created repository of Auser, to which it obviously pushed.

My foremost problem is that I can't push under Auser, but my curiosity is more on how am I able to push as Buser to the repository owned by Auser, without Buser even having any ssh key set up?

Are there any other mechanism by which git bash uses to login to github, in order to push, apart from ssh keys?

Comment: `Buser commited 2 minutes ago` does not imply that Buser was the one who pushed the change. You are confusing two things: the committer info which is stored in a git commit and is based on the local git config, and GitHub user info which is what the ssh keys determine.

Comment: why do you say I am confusing them? I already mentioned that Buser is not in the local nor global git config.